# javascript in mongoshell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, query, json

I want to make a join query in mongodb. Mongo doesn't have any join operator so i have to split the query in two parts. 
first:

```
var a = db.articoli.find({_id: 4010}, {ordini:1});
var b = a[0].ordini;
```

to obtain an array of articoli in var a;
var b will be an array of ordini, each value of this array is the id of the collection ordini.

then:

```
for (var i = 0; i < b.lenght; i++) {
  db.ordini.find({_id: b[i]}).pretty())
}
```

but when i run this script on the mongo shell, i get no error, but also no result.
If I use put just this command in the shell:

```
db.ordini.find({_id: b[0]}).pretty())
```

I obtain the requested document.
Why if i put the instruction in the for loop, the shell soesn't give me back nothing???

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has supported a [`$lookup` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) since 3.2 (Dec 2015). With `$lookup` you can perform a left outer join to an unsharded collection, and in MongoDB 3.6+ the syntax has expanded to allow [other join conditions and uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries).

An example query to achieve your joined outcome would look like:

```js
db.articoli.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        _id: 4010
    }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: "ordini",
        localField: "ordini",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "ordini"
    }}
])
```

Assuming the original `articoli` documents include an array of  `ordini` primary key values, this will populate an `ordini` array in the aggregation result with documents from the `ordini` collection.

> when i run this script on the mongo shell, i get no error, but also no result

The `mongo` shell only implicity prints the last value returned in a statement. If you want output printed within your for loop, you should use an explicit `print()`. For examples, see: [Iterate a Cursor in the `mongo` Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor).

Comment: Really helpful thank you very much :)))